# VS2012 Unable to create MVC4 web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-tools

When I try to create any template of ASP.NET MVC4 Web Application I got error:

```
The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
```

I am running VS2012 Ultimate on Windows 8. I have installed ASP.NET MVC 4 and all Updates for VS. Also I have been installed Web Tools 2012.2.

Tried to re-install and repair - no success.

Comment: Try opening visual studio as an administrator -> right click the icon and select 'Run as Administrator'.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the Nuget Package Manager.
2. If Nuget by it´s own doesn´t solve the problem, install visual studio 2012 update 4 (or last update to date). This solved the problem for me on VS 2012. On vs2010 the Nuget installation solved it.